# P:messages duplicando mensagens PrimeFaces JSF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jsf

Problemas com duplicação de Mensagens no p:messages do PrimeFaces.

Na aplicação eu chamo este método apenas para inserir a mensagem. Segue o código:

```
public class FacesUtil {

    public static boolean isPostback() {
        return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback();
    }

    public static boolean isNotPostback() {
        return !isPostback();
    }

    public static void addErrorMessage(String message) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, message, message));
    }

    public static void addInfoMessage(String message) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, message, message));
    }
```

Alguém sabe informar o motivo ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrVp7.png

Comment: Cara assim fica difícil, coloca código para nós saber o problema, quantos mais códigos melhor.

Comment: Na aplicação eu chamo este método apenas para inserir a mensagem:
http://pastebin.com/e8E7eLV1

Comment: para ajudar, poste mais código.

Comment: Agradeço a resposta de todos, mas o problema estava estrutural. Já foi resolvido.

Answer (score 0):

Amigos, não tem problema estrutural nenhum.

É simples resolver a mensagem  duplicada, So precisa tirar showDetail="true" ou colocar ele para false showDetail="false"

Só isso já resolve a duplicação da mensagem.

Att, 
Thiago Neri